# How to enable windows Authentication in IIS 7.5?

Tags: iis-7.5, windows-authentication

i need to enable Windows Autenthication for a specific website on IIS 7.5

If I open "Autenthication" I just see 3 options:

Anonymous

Based on Form

ASP.NET Representation

(3 above translated by me, I have italian IIS)

I've been told that I should see also "Windows AUtenthication" in that list.

In "modules" for the same website I see "Windows Authentication", with code "System.Web.Secuitiry.WindowsAuthenticationModule", Module type is "Managed",and Type is "Inherited".

I am totally stuck.

Comment: Try this help page from Microsoft https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/authentication/windowsauthentication/

Answer (score 3):

Do you have the Windows Authentication feature installed for IIS?

In PowerShell:

```
Get-WindowsFeature Web-Windows-Auth
```

Is it installed? If not, then:

```
Add-WindowsFeature Web-Windows-Auth
```

Comment: `Import-Package`?

Comment: My bad, for some reason I thought that was necessary for the `WindowsFeature` cmdlets

Comment: I don't understand your answer. I tried to execute `Get-WindowsFeature Web-Windows-Auth` from Powershell but I get an error.

Comment: And the error is? If you prefer you can install the feature from the GUI.

Comment: @ChrisMcKeown the error is in italian, anyway if you tell me plaese how to do from the GUI it would be great. Thanks. Ithought this was wasy to find by googling but i did not succeed.